# Aquire source files from jQuery UI Tabs demo?

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, tabs

I'd like to use the code from http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/tabs/vertical.html but how do I access the relevant source files (js and css files)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do a Control+U (or a view source in your browser), you'll be able to see what files are being loaded.

Another option is the JSView add-on for Firefox, which will list the JS/CSS files loaded in a given page https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/jsview/

Comment: Thanks thats a handy plug-in.  Its too bad the author linked to a bunch of irrelevant js and css files though.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it's a standard jQuery UI widget: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/. See http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/getting-started for instructions on how to download, install and use it. The vertical tabs in the demo are achieved by using CSS which is located in the HTML file itself right at the beginning.